# After signup redirect user to login page

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth , after signing up on site the user is sent to profile page but I want the user to go to the login page after signing up with a message "your account has been created"

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first override `get_login_redirect_url()` method from `django-allauth`.

And then for sending message use **[django messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-a-message)**.

**settings.py:**

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'yourapp.adapter.AccountAdapter' # ---> change it to your path
```

**yourapp/adapter.py:**

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from django.contrib import messages

class AccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def get_login_redirect_url(self, request):
        messages.success(request, 'Your account created.')
        return 'url/to/your/page' # --> change it to your page url
```

> **Answer update after comment:**

To logout after account creation.

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

logout(request)  # --> put it before return above
```

Comment: After trying this I am getting infinite redirect loop on console and Page isn't redirecting properly on my browser. I am returning '/accounts/login'

Comment: @AkhilGarg, that will definitely happen. You are going to login page after login and that will again do login. So it will be infinite loop. Redirect to some different page like `/home` or something like that.

Comment: Try that and do let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: redirecting to  `/home` is working. Is it possible that after a user signs up to the site rather then just logging in the user gets redirected  to  login page  and then they have to  login in order  to  access the site

Comment: Yeah possible, but it is not ideal. First you do logout suing code before redirect, but we shouldn't do it.

Comment: how to  logout before using redirect?

Comment: @AkhilGarg, check the updated answer. And if this has resolves your, please do vote up and mark the answer as accepted. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

in **views.py**

```
def register(request):
users=User.objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        messages.success(request, f'Account has been created successfully!, User can now login')
        return redirect('login') #login is the name of login view in urls.py
else:
    form = RegisterForm()
return render(request, 'users/home/register.html', {'form': form,'users':users})
```

Comment: this is working when I am creating my forms manually when I am using all-auth it isn't working